# Java compareTo Dates cannot be equal

Tags: java, validation, date, compareto

I am trying to compare 2 dates, the first date is from the MySQL database, and the second is from the current date.

as you can see below, there are different dates in the database

[image: Dates records in database] 
But the problem is that I got 3 if statements, which should tell my program if the Database date is before, after or equal the current date. The Before and After statements should work, but it can see the date 2018-06-12 should be equal to the current date so it ends in the "before statement".

Hope you can see what I have done wrong.

```
private static void Resetter() throws ParseException, SQLException {
    String host = "****";
    String username = "root";
    String mysqlpassword = "";

    //Querys
    String query = "select * from accounts";
    String queryy = "update accounts set daily_search_count = 0 where id = ?";
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, username, mysqlpassword);
    Statement st = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);

    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
    dateFormat.setTimeZone( TimeZone.getTimeZone( "UTC" ));
    Date currentDate = new Date();

    while(rs.next()){
        System.out.println(dateFormat.format(currentDate));
        if (rs.getDate(5).compareTo(currentDate) > 0) {
           // System.out.println("Database-date is after currentDate");
        } else if (rs.getDate(5).compareTo(currentDate) < 0) {
           // System.out.println("Database-date is before currentDate");
            PreparedStatement updatexdd = con.prepareStatement(queryy);
            updatexdd.setInt(1, rs.getInt(1));
            int updatexdd_done = updatexdd.executeUpdate();
        } else if (rs.getDate(5).compareTo(currentDate) == 0) {
           // System.out.println("Database-date is equal to currentDate");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Any other");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated (I'm not sure what you're asking) but the answer will either be >0, <0, or zero. There's at least one extra condition, and one extra condition expression.

Comment: It is because according to the Date 2018-06-12 from database should be equal to the current date. But in this case, it doesn't. I just end in the < 0

Comment: Yes.  `rs.getDate()` returns just a date - there's no time component (or more accurately, the time component is midnight).  But `new Date()` gives you the current date _and time_.

Comment: Use dateFormat.format(rs.getDate(5)) in all if statements, so all will be in same format.

Comment: @kristoffer Right, but what I'm saying is that you don't need the `== 0` else, because if it's not <0 or >0 it's the only other option.

Comment: What you need is `LocalDate` from [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). It’s a date without time of day, so cannot play such tricks on you. Plus, `java.time` is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
Instant instant = myResultSet.getObject( … , Instant.class ) ;  // Retrieve a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` value in database as an `Instant` for a date with time-of-day in UTC with a resolution as fine as nanoseconds.
LocalDate ld = instant.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ).toLocalDate() ;  // Extract a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

if ( ld.isBefore( today ) ) { … }       // Compare `LocalDate` objects.
else if ( ld.isEqual( today ) ) { … }
else if ( ld.isAfter( today ) ) { … }
else { … handle error }
```

## java.time

You are using, and misusing, troublesome old date-time classes.

As others pointed out:

- A SQL-standard `DATE` type holds only a date without a time-of-day and without a timezone
- The legacy `java.util.Date` class is misnamed, holding both a date *and* a time-of-day in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).
- The legacy `java.sql.Date` class pretends to hold only a date but actually has a time-of-day because this class inherits from the one above, while the documentation tells us to ignore that fact in our usage. (Yes, this is confusing, and is a bad design, a clumsy hack.)

Never use the `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, `java.sql.Timestamp`, `java.sql.Date`, and related classes. Instead, use only the sane *java.time* classes. They lead the industry in clean-design and depth of understanding of date-time handling gleaned from the experience of their predecessor, the [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project.

For date-only value, stored in SQL-standard database type of `DATE`, use [`java.time.LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html).

```
LocalDate ld = myResultSet.get( … , LocalDate.class ) ;  // Retrieving from database.
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , ld ) ;  // Storing in database.
```

For a date with time-of-day in UTC value, stored in a SQL-standard database type of `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`, use [`java.time.Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html). The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant instant = myResultSet.get( … , Instant.class ) ;  // Retrieving from database.
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , instant ) ;  // Storing in database.
```

For comparing in Java, use the `isEqual`, `isBefore`, `isAfter`, `equals`, or `compare` methods.

```
Boolean overdue = someLocalDate.isAfter( otherLocalDate ) ;
```

## Time zone

Time zone is crucial in determining a date and a time-of-day from a moment (`Instant`/`TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`).

After retrieving your `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` value from the database as an `Instant`, adjust into the [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) or [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) whose wall-clock time you want to use in perceiving a date & time-of-day. For a time zone, apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime` object. For an offset-from-UTC, apply a `ZoneOffset` to get a `OffsetDateTime` object. In either case, extract a date-only value by calling `toLocalDate` to get a `LocalDate` object.

In your case, you apparently want to perceive the date as UTC. So apply the constant, `ZoneOffset.UTC` to get an `OffsetDateTime`

```
OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;  
LocalDate ld = odt.toLocalDate() ;   // Extract a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.
```

We want to compare with current date in UTC.

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;  // Specify the offset/zone by which you want to perceive the current date.
```

Compare.

```
if ( ld.isBefore( today ) ) { … }
else if ( ld.isEqual( today ) ) { … }
else if ( ld.isAfter( today ) ) { … }
else { … handle error }
```

## ISO 8601

Avoid unnecessarily using custom formats such as "yyyy/MM/dd". Use standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats whenever possible.

For a date-only value, that would be YYYY-MM-DD.

```
String output = LocalDate.now().toString() ;  // Ex: 2018-01-23
```

## Example with *H2*

Here is a full example of writing, querying, and reading `LocalDate` objects from a database column of SQL-standard `DATE` type.

Using the [*H2 Database Engine*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H2_(DBMS)), as I am not a [MySQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL) user. Creating an in-memory database rather than writing to storage. I assume the code would be nearly the same for MySQL.

```
try (
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:h2:mem:trashme" )
) {
    String sql = "CREATE TABLE " + "tbl_" + " (\n" +
                     "  uuid_ UUID DEFAULT random_uuid() , \n" +  // Every table should have a primary key.
                     "  when_ DATE \n" +                          // Three columns per the Question.
                     " );";
    try (
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement() ;
    ) {
        stmt.execute( sql );
    }

    sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_ ( when_ ) VALUES ( ? ) ;";
    LocalDate start = LocalDate.of( 2018 , Month.JANUARY , 23 );
    LocalDate ld = start;  // Keep the `start` object for use later.
    try (
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement( sql )
    ) {
        for ( int i = 1 ; i <= 10 ; i++ ) {
            ps.setObject( 1 , ld );
            ps.executeUpdate();
            // Prepare for next loop.
            int randomNumber = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt( 1 , 5 + 1 ); // Pass minimum & ( maximum + 1 ).
            ld = ld.plusDays( randomNumber ); // Add a few days, an arbitrary number.
        }
    }

    // Dump all rows, to verify our populating of table.
    System.out.println( "Dumping all rows: uuid_ & when_ columns." );
    sql = "SELECT uuid_ , when_ FROM tbl_ ; ";
    int rowCount = 0;
    try (
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement() ;
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( sql ) ;
    ) {
        while ( rs.next() ) {
            rowCount++;
            UUID uuid = rs.getObject( 1 , UUID.class );
            LocalDate localDate = rs.getObject( 2 , LocalDate.class );
            System.out.println( uuid + " " + localDate );
        }
    }
    System.out.println( "Done dumping " + rowCount + " rows." );


    // Dump all rows, to verify our populating of table.
    System.out.println( "Dumping rows where `when_` is after " + start + ": uuid_ & when_ columns." );
    sql = "SELECT uuid_ , when_ FROM tbl_ WHERE when_ > ? ; ";
    rowCount = 0; // Reset count.
    final PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement( sql );
    ps.setObject( 1 , start );
    try (
        ps ;
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery() ;
    ) {
        while ( rs.next() ) {
            rowCount++;
            UUID uuid = rs.getObject( 1 , UUID.class );
            LocalDate localDate = rs.getObject( 2 , LocalDate.class );
            System.out.println( uuid + " " + localDate );
        }
    }
    System.out.println( "Done dumping " + rowCount + " rows." );

} catch ( SQLException eArg ) {
    eArg.printStackTrace();
}
```

When run.

```
Dumping all rows: uuid_ & when_ columns.
e9c75998-cd67-4ef9-9dce-6c1eed170387 2018-01-23
741c1452-e224-4e5e-95bc-904d8db58b39 2018-01-27
413de43c-a1be-40b6-9ccf-a9b7d9ba873c 2018-01-31
e2aa148f-48b6-4be6-a0fe-f2881b6b5a63 2018-02-03
f498003c-2d8b-446e-ac55-6d7568ce61c3 2018-02-06
c41606d7-8c05-4bba-9f8e-2a0d1f1bb31a 2018-02-09
3df3abe3-1865-4632-99c4-6cd74883c1ee 2018-02-10
914153fe-34f2-4e4f-a91b-944314994839 2018-02-13
96436bdf-80ee-4afe-b55d-f240140ace6a 2018-02-16
82b43f7b-077d-45c1-8c4f-f5b30dfdd44a 2018-02-19
Done dumping 10 rows.
Dumping rows where `when_` is after 2018-01-23: uuid_ & when_ columns.
741c1452-e224-4e5e-95bc-904d8db58b39 2018-01-27
413de43c-a1be-40b6-9ccf-a9b7d9ba873c 2018-01-31
e2aa148f-48b6-4be6-a0fe-f2881b6b5a63 2018-02-03
f498003c-2d8b-446e-ac55-6d7568ce61c3 2018-02-06
c41606d7-8c05-4bba-9f8e-2a0d1f1bb31a 2018-02-09
3df3abe3-1865-4632-99c4-6cd74883c1ee 2018-02-10
914153fe-34f2-4e4f-a91b-944314994839 2018-02-13
96436bdf-80ee-4afe-b55d-f240140ace6a 2018-02-16
82b43f7b-077d-45c1-8c4f-f5b30dfdd44a 2018-02-19
Done dumping 9 rows.
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: This is so much more straightforward. And gives you an upgrade to the modern API on top. Warmly recommended.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! but now I am facing a new issue, I don't know why, but when y try to store the dates in the DB nothing happens, I get no errors or anything and the date won't be updated, got any idea?
https://gist.github.com/kris914g/16b36602fc8edcae2f2929c818db391f

Comment: @kristoffer I added a complete example with H2 database. As for [your linked example code](https://gist.github.com/kris914g/16b36602fc8edcae2f2929c818db391f): (a) You declare two placeholders in your `updateDate` SQL but you only set one of those two. (b) You never get around to executing that prepared statement. So no update is attempted. (c) Is back-tick character allowed in MySQL syntax? Not in standard SQL as far as I know. (d) Tip: Make use of try-with-resources statements, newly improved in Java 9.

Answer (score 4):

`ResultSet#getDate` returns a date with the time part removed. Instantiating a new `Date` object **does** contain the time, so you'll have to remove it yourself. E.g.:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
Date currentDate = cal.getTime();
```

Comment: Or make use of the date/time API introduced in Java 8, `sqlDate.toLocalDate().compareTo(LocalDate.now())` :P

Comment: Thanks, i had never thought about the time was included as well

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on the Java version that you are using. If you are using Java 6 or Java 7 then this approach will be the easiest:

As you are dealing with java.sql.Date anyways, you can use this quick approach to get Date without time part and compare java.sql.Date to java.sql.Date:

```
Date currentDate = new java.sql.Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

You can also use `java.util.Date#before` and `java.util.Date#after` methods for the better code readability:

```
while(rs.next()){
    System.out.println(dateFormat.format(currentDate));
    if (rs.getDate(5).after(currentDate)) {
       // System.out.println("Database-date is after currentDate");
    } else if (rs.getDate(5).before(currentDate)) {
       // System.out.println("Database-date is before currentDate");
        PreparedStatement updatexdd = con.prepareStatement(queryy);
        updatexdd.setInt(1, rs.getInt(1));
        int updatexdd_done = updatexdd.executeUpdate();
    } else {
       // System.out.println("Database-date is equal to currentDate");
    }
}
```

If you are using Java 8 then you can use new Java time API.